# Rails 3 Jquery making select tag unobtrusive

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I would like to make **select** more unobtrusive.

I would like that when user selects particular options jquery automatically sends appropriate request, for instance **/conroller/action/1**

```
<form id="some-id" method="post" data-remote="true" action="/templates?locale=uk" >
<select id="user-templates" data-remote="true" name="user-templates">
   <option href="/controller/action/1" data-remote="true" value="1">option-1</option>
   <option href="/controller/action/2" data-remote="true" value="2">option-2</option>
   <option href="/controller/action/3" data-remote="true" value="3">option-3</option>
   <option href="/controller/action/4" data-remote="true" value="4">option-4</option>
</select>
</form>
```

But instead currently it sends strange request like **http://127.0.0.1:3000/templates?locale=uk&some-id=1** according to selected option.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `href` attribute for `option` tag. Your options is:

Method 1.

```
<option onclick="location.href = '/controller/action/1'" 
  data-remote="true" value="1">option-1</option>
```

Method 2. JavaScript:

```
$("#user-templates").change(function() {
  location.href = "/controller/action/" + $("#user-templates").val();
});
```

Or, if you want to send request in background:

```
$("#user-templates").change(function() {
  $.get("/controller/action/" + $("#user-templates").val());
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that is unobtrusively?

Comment: Hm. Do you mean ajax request under "unobtrusively"? I've added code for ajax request in my answer.

Comment: It's not possible because such behaviour is not supported by HTML.